# Count number of clicks on radio button

Tags: jquery

I have group of radio buttons like this:
`<form>
<input class="answer" name="answer" value="10" type="radio">ans0<br>
<input class="answer" name="answer" value="11" type="radio">ans1<br>
</form>`
And I have place on page where I write how many times did you click on any radio button.

`<p>Clicked:</p>
<p id="clicked">0</p>`

I need jquery to count all those clicks. Can you help me?

Comment: I've tried
`var count = 0;

$(document).load(function(){
  $("#answer").change(function(){
    count=count+1;
    $("#clicked").text(count);
  });
});`

Comment: @pfdsppp You need to specificy what you want in the question - My answer will count everytime you click the radio , like you said , if you want it to count everytime it is changed - that would be slightly different code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a click-event listener to your radio buttons. Then in the callback you read the current number in the element with id clicked, you parse it into a number, add 1, and write the new value to the element.

Something like this:

```
// Attach a click-event listener to your radio-buttons​
$("input[type='radio']")​.on("click", function () {
    // Cache the element
    var elm = $("#clicked");
    // Read the current value
    var count = parseInt(elm.text(), 10);
    // Update the element with the new value
    elm.text(count + 1);    
});​​​​​​​​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/A8tZd/)

Comment: is that what he wanted ? or to count the clicking of each radio seperatly ?  I'm confused

Comment: @ScottSelby I believe this is what OP is after, but I agree with you that it could be interpreted otherwise, as your comment on the question suggest. However, until the question has been clarified, I think I'll leave my answer as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `click` function to capture clicks.

```
var counter = 0
$('input[name=answer]').click(function() {
  counter++
  $('#clicked').text(counter); // update text
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
$(function(){
    var clicked = 0,
        radios = $('form input[type="radio"]'),
        clickBlock = $('#clicked');

    radios.click(function(){
        clicked++;
        clickBlock.html(clicked);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is of a [working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kZuca/) , I put an extra attribute in the radio box html to store the number of clicks.  If this is an option for you I think it makes for effecient clean code , then there is only one block of  code written to handle the click event and display clicks for every radio button - no matter how many you may have

```
<input class="answer" name="answer" value="10" type="radio" data-clicked="0">ans0<br>
<input class="answer" name="answer" value="11" type="radio" data-clicked="0">ans1<br>​

$(function(){
    $('.answer').click(function(){
       var numOfClicks = $(this).attr('data-clicked');
       numOfClicks = (numOfClicks * 1) + 1;
       $(this).attr('data-clicked', numOfClicks);
       alert(numOfClicks);
    });    
});​
```